# Programmatically setting a custom customer attribute

Tags: magento, attributes, custom-attributes

Is it possible to programmatically set the value of a custom customer attribute? I have scoured the internet for an answer to this, but to no avail :(.

I know that you can access one using this method:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$measurements_taken = $customer->getResource()->getAttribute('measurements_taken')->getFrontend()->getValue($customer);
```

but I'm not too sure on how to set the value of this attribute. I tried the following:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->setMeasurementsTaken('TO_CHECK');
$customer->saveAttribute($customer,'measurements_taken');
```

but it throws an error saying something about an invalid method.

Comment: complete error please .........................

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After making your updates,

```
$customer->save();
```

or

```
$customer->setMeasurementsTaken('TO_CHECK')->save();
```

Comment: it won't help with his error "an error saying something about an invalid method" ...

Comment: @Bixi How will it not help? `Mage_Customer_Model_Session::getCustomer()` returns an instance of `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer`, which *does not* have a `saveAttribute()` method but *does* have a `save()` method.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't throw any errors! However, it did not change the attribute's value in the back-end :(

Comment: @NateTheGreatt You may need to set some additional scope-related info based on your local configuration. You can debug this in `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_beforeSave()`

Comment: I realized that it was a drop-down select attribute! Changing it to a text field attribute worked like a charm :).
However, for the sake of knowledge, do you know how to change a drop-down select attribute?